# Правильно ли расставлены запятые

Tags: пунктуация

На фоне такого масштабного места, чувствуешь себя мелкой сошкой и понимаешь всю ничтожность своего существования.
Это очень широкие водопады, а вблизи так просто огромные.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая после слова МЕСТА лишняя, она ничем не мотивирована. Другие знаки поставлены верно.

Answer (score 1):

Первая запятая не нужна

Answer (score 0):

А разве не так:"А вблизи, так просто, огромные"?

Comment: Нет, запятые лишние.